# Does it make any difference if a Window setTimeout is made to be dependent on jQuery DOM ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, document-ready

I just have some code which I want executed a few seconds after the page is loaded. For that I could do this..

```
 setTimeout(function() {
            alert("Now I am free");
    }, 3000);
```

Or I could make it fire on document ready...

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

   setTimeout(function() {
     alert("Now I am free");
    }, 3000);
});
```

What is the difference between these two approaches? Which is better?

Comment: `.ready()` will add a bit more of a delay because the `seTimeout` code isn't set until after the DOM is ready. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

The first approach (just set a delay) **has a timing hole in it**: the timer could go off before the page has finished loading.

You may consider this unlikely, and it may be unlikely on your system. But consider the visitor whose device has marginal memory capacity, continuous memory faults are occurring because the OS is trying to update itself at the same time as 15 open tabs in the web browser are trying to do background AJAX calls, and the browser is showing "not responding" across the top. And, say, the browser takes another 30 seconds to start responding again. *This is not a fictitious, scenario*.

Using the document ready mechanism to start the timer guarantees the DOM can be manipulated by call back code when the timer goes off. You could also add an event listener to window "load" event to do the same thing in plain vanilla JavaScript.

Starting the timer in a script block right at the end of the <body> section may also remove the risk of the timer going off too early.